# How can i sort list with dart?

Tags: sorting, flutter, dart

I have list like that `list = ['1','5','10','25','50','100','250'];`

I sort list like that `list..sort((a, b) => a.compareTo(b);`

But return

> 1 - 10 - 100 - 25 - 250 - 5 - 50

How can i sort like that return

> 1 - 5 - 10 - 25 - 50 - 100 - 250

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to first convert String list into int list then you can sort them.

```
List<String> list = ['1', '5', '10', '25', '50', '100', '250'];
List<int> lint = list.map(int.parse).toList();
lint.sort();
print(lint);
```

Comment: Do you even need the comparator function in this case?

Comment: Yes we don't need int list have built in sort method. I will update my answer soon. Thank you for let me know.

Answer (score 2):

The reason is your numbers are represented as `String` objects and is therefore sorted alphabetically and not in order of values. To do that we need to convert each `String` object into a `int` object before we compare the values.

The previous mentioned solution works but you will end up with List of `int` objects since it first converts the `List<String>` to `List<int>` before sorting.

If you don't want that, you can do the following which maintain the original representation of the numbers:

```
void main() {
  final list = ['1', '5', '10', '25', '50', '100', '250'];
  list.sort((a, b) => int.parse(a).compareTo(int.parse(b)));
  print(list); // [1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250]
}
```

If the list are very long, it would be more efficient to use the other mentioned solution and after sorting, convert the `List<int>` back into `List<String>`:

```
void main() {
  List<String> list = ['1', '5', '10', '25', '50', '100', '250'];
  List<int> lint = list.map(int.parse).toList();
  lint.sort();
  list = lint.map((i) => i.toString()).toList();
  print(list); // [1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100, 250]
}
```